# ListView Lollipop doesn't show all the information

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a list view that works fine in some version of android, but in lollipop the list view doesn't show all the information (just 1 string of 5). In my app I have just an activity that extends of AppCompatActivity, here my adapter

```
    public class PromoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<PromoObject> originalData = null;
    public PromoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PromoObject> listArray) {
        super(context, R.layout.home_promo_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.originalData = listArray ;
    }

    public static class Row
    {
        public TextView labelPromo;
        public ImageView imagePromo;
        public TextView titlePromo;
        public TextView daysPromo;
        public TextView schedulePromo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  originalData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_promo_item, null);
            // configure view holder
            Row viewHolder = new Row();

            viewHolder.labelPromo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label_promo);

            viewHolder.imagePromo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo_promo);

            viewHolder.titlePromo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title_promo);

            viewHolder.daysPromo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.days_promo);

            viewHolder.schedulePromo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.schedule_promo);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        Row holder = (Row) rowView.getTag();
        PromoObject itm = originalData.get(position);
        holder.labelPromo.setText(itm.getPromoValue());
        holder.imagePromo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pizzahut);
        holder.titlePromo.setText(itm.getTitlePromo());
        holder.daysPromo.setText(itm.getDays());
        holder.schedulePromo.setText(itm.getSchedule());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here mi XML file: home_promo_item

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/box_info"
        android:background="@color/promo_1"
        android:id="@+id/box_promo">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-25%"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/label_promo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box_promo"
        android:id="@+id/box_info"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/box_promo"
        android:background="@drawable/border_right">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pizzahut"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/logo_promo"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_promo"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title_promo"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="EN TODAS NUESTRAS PIZZAS"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/days_promo"
                android:text="Promoción Valida de Lunes a Jueves"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_promo"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title_promo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/schedule_promo"
                android:text="de 12:00 m a 5:00pm."
                android:layout_below="@+id/days_promo"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/days_promo" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post home_promo_item.

Comment: Post ListView item XML layout. Your ViewHolder is unnecessary

Comment: home_promo_item ready in the post!  @dieter_h

Comment: By "just 1 string of 5" you mean the list displays one item? Or in each item there is only one string displayed (that's what I thought at the beginning but it is confusing because you actually have only 4 strings). If the list displays just one item - are you placing the `ListView` inside another scrollable container?

Comment: In each item show one string of 5 that must display, and my listView is only inside a LinearLayout @N.T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lollipop we need to set the color of the strings because it put it white automatically, for that reason I couldn't see all the strings from my object.

Sorry about my English, it isn't my mother tongue

Answer (score 0):

Post home_promo_item, probably your LinearLayout is HORIZONTAl, while it should be VERTICAL to display rows inside a ListView.